# How to execute multi commands from one gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm trying to execute multi commands in gnome-terminal?
I came across an example as the below,

```
sudo gnome-terminal --window --wait --tab --active --geometry=120X60 \
    --title="$1" --working-directory="$code_directory"\
    -- bash -c "$file_path; exec bash"
```

It only works one command.

If I want to execute multiple command in step by step, for example `"cd /home"` and then execute `"make"` then `something`.. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: `$file_path; exec bash` are two commands though, so what do you mean by `It only works one command.`?

Comment: @TomYan Yes. they are working as one command.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really not seeing what you mean. How could two commands "work as" one command? (I mean like, in terms of their "effect".) Are you saying that only the first command is executed or what? (And what was the "Yes" for?)

Comment: @TomYan Sorry my bad. I mean that  that 3 command are working at once. Actually I expected that they are excuted one by one.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be possible unless you use `&` instead of `;` between them...

Comment: You are running a single command, `sudo gnome-terminal`, which is told to run `bash -c` with the argument `"$file_path; exec bash"`.  The command `$file_path` will run first inside `gnome-terminal`, then the command `exec bash` will run inside the same `gnome-terminal`.  So you are running "multiple commands" "one by one" already.  If you are expecting something different, please be descriptive in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GracefulRestart Thanks